# ndb.transactional How to group entities?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This app is for rental service. When tool is handed out I need to save customers key on tools' 'who_has' attribute and add tools key to handout order. If anything goes wrong, I need to delete all previously written 'who_has' attributes.

I figured Trancastions is the way to do it. so here's my code

```
def get_tools(tool_ids):
    tools =[]
    for t in tool_ids:
            tool = classes.ToolUnits.get_by_id(int(t))
            tools.append(tool)

    return tools

@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def process_handout(self):
    customer_id = self.request.get("customer")
    tool_ids = self.request.get("units")

    if not customer_id == 'false' and (not tool_ids=="[]" or not tool_ids):
        customer = classes.Customers.get_by_id(int(customer_id))

        order = classes.Orders(
            customer = customer.key,
            handout = True,
            transferred = [],
            booked = [],
        )

        tools = get_tools(json.loads(tool_ids))

        for tool in tools:

            if not tool.who_has:
                tool.who_has = customer.key
                order.transferred.append(tool.key)
                tool.put()
            else:
                # if tool is already taken
                order.booked.append(tool.key)

        order.put()
        self.redirect('/order/%s' % order.key.id())
    else:
        self.redirect('/tools')
```

works fine woth two tools, but 8 tools throws an error:
`BadRequestError: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.`

Apperantly each `tool.put()` is treated as an entity group. How do I unite them under a single group?

I tried docs, but it's all chinese to me. Can you explain on my example, plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using cross-group (`xg=True`) transactions which are [limited to 5 entities participating in the transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Python_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction).

Entity groups are defined by an [ancestor path](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths): this simply means that for a particular entity (or entities) you define the parent entity, and for that parent entity you can again define a parent, basically defining a tree of entities. All those entities belong to the same entity group. The root of the group is the entity at the root of the tree: an entity that other entities defined as parent (directly or indirectly), but itself it has no parent defined.

If you do not define the parent of an entity and you also do not use this entity as the parent of other entities, then this entity is the root of it's own entity group.

A simplified rationale: entity group basically means "putting all entities on the same machine", so that GAE can easily make transactional changes on them.

The limitation is that entity group (= all entities inside an entity group) can only be updated once per second. So you need to be careful how you structure your data. One good way is to use user as a root of the entity group, since users behave independently and tend to not create multiple requests in very short time.

Hope this clear up the things a bit.

Comment: So, I guess the best way to do it would be assigning a customer or user as an ancestor in `get_tools(tool_ids)` to all tool entities before handing them to transactional function?

Is assigning ancestor counted  as update in this "updated once per second" limitation?

Comment: Ancestor path is part of the key, so you can not just add it later. You need to do this when entity is first created.

Comment: that is bad. Thanks, I'll have to think about it. Maybe I should make my own transaction script, that caches all changes made until all changes are done successfully... or probably someone already wrote it